# why powerpivot completly brokes if there is no values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

Can't understand simple thing about PowerPivot.

Why this works:

[image]

When this doesn't:
[image]

I have just removed attribute "Earned" from "Values" group and PowerPivot completely brokes (in my opinion): start listing ALL movies from "ActordMovies" table, not only those that are related to the actor.

How PoverPoint "join" tables?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a pivot table in excel is to group data, and display a value. So not adding a field can lead to wrong results.

Correct Result: all rows/column fields are in 1 table (when no field in values field)
Wrong Result: Row/Column fields are from different tables (when no field in values field)

When Adding a field in the Values field, you will have a good result.
Solution if you don't want to display earnings: 
add a calculated measure that counts the rows in the ActorMovies Table.

formula: Cnt:=CountRows(ActorMovies)

[PowerPivotModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mhZu.png)